# How do can I use OpenCV imshow to display the most recent image in a loop without keyboard feedback

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I am running an image processing loop with OpenCV in Python and I would like to display the most recent image mask in my `imshow` window. So whenever the loop calculates a new mask, it updates the `imshow` window (at about 6Hz). However, I can't get `imshow` to return control without waiting for a keyboard interrupt. Any suggestions? Is there a better library to use for this?

Comment: use either `cv::waitKey(10)` equivalent in python (not wait for keyboard input but wait for keyboard input OR until 10 ms expired - openCV NEEDS some wait-time for displaying images) or use some GUI library and display the image there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without code this is a guess. BUT!

I imagine you are currently using `cv2.waitKey` to wait until there is a keyboard input:

```
cv2.waitKey(33)
if k==27:    # Esc key to stop
    break
```

What you need to do is use `cv2.waitKey` to wait a set amount of time, say 1 ms.

```
# Wait 1 milliseconds. Specifying 0 means forever, so we don't want that
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: waitKey(0) is a special  case to wait forever until a keypress. Use 10-20ms if you want it to just show and continue

Comment: Worked great!  I did have to use a discrete value for waitKey.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is log the image to a folder in the loop's directory if it's not totally essential for the image to be displayed in real time.

```
cv2.imwrite('image_logs/image_' + str(image_count) + '.jpeg', image)
```

For instance. Keeping track of images can easily be done with a counter.

You could also use waitkey - which will delay for the number of milliseconds in the parenthesis. Sometimes I have problems with this though (I use an rpi, quite slow!) so I tend to go for the logging option.

```
cv2.waitKey(50) #wait for 50ms
```